# Which side of an ESF has better armour?

Tags: planetside-2

The unconventional aircraft physics in Planetside 2 makes it possible to turn either by rolling in the direction you want to turn (like in real life) or by rolling in the opposite direction. When turning on an attacker, this gives you the choice of whether to present him your roof or your undercarriage, so I'm interested to know which side is more durable.

Citations with your answer, please :-)

Comment: My guess is it is all the same where you hit them, aslong as you hit them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ESF have no hitzones, so no matter where you hit you always do the same amount of damage. You can expose any side you want.

Source: [PS2 Calculator](http://www.ps2calc.com/#vehicle1=ESF)

Bonus:
In Planetside 2, the fastest way to turn is to roll 90° into the opposite direction of where you want to turn, then pitch down, i.e. towards the belly of the ESF, and yaw in the direction of your turn.